# Remove class name sibling component when click the current component and make toggling in current to remove class it self

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm new in react and try to make a button that will remove the sibling class if i click in the current button, and also the current button can remove it self class (toggling),i already try and it seems im not find the clue. here my code below .

```
export default class Child extends Component {
render(){
    return(
      <button
         onClick={this.props.onClick}
         className={this.props.activeMode ? 'active' : ''}>
         {this.props.text}
      </button>
     )
   }
}

export default class Parent extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     selectedIndex: null,
   };
 }

  handleClick (selectedIndex) {
   this.setState({
    selectedIndex,
   });
  }

  render () {
    const array = ["Button 1","Button 2"];
    return (
     <div>
       {array.map((obj, index) => {
       const active = this.state.selectedIndex === index;
       return <Child
       text={obj}
       activeMode={active}
       key={index}
       onClick={() => this.handleClick(index)} />
       })}
     </div>
     )
   }
 }
```

Comment: It's not clear. What do you expect when button clicked?

Comment: sorry if it's not clear for you, let say  i have 2 button if i click the first button it will add a class, but when i click the second button it will remove the class name from the first one at the same time it will add a class in the second button, also i can remove the class from the second button if i click the second button it self

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not shure that I understood your clearly right

Did you meen something like this?

```js
class Child extends React.Component {
render(){
    return(
      <button
         onClick={this.props.onClick}
         className={this.props.activeMode ? 'active' : ''}>
         {this.props.text}
      </button>
     )
   }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     selectedIndex: null,
   };
 }

  handleClick (selectedIndex) {
    let selected = this.state.selectedIndex === selectedIndex ? null : selectedIndex; 
    this.setState({
 selectedIndex: selected,
    });
  }

  render () {
    const array = ["Button 1","Button 2"];
    return (
    <div>
    {
        array.map((obj, index) => {
        return <Child text={obj}
                    activeMode={this.state.selectedIndex === index}
                    key={index}
                    onClick={() => this.handleClick(index)} />
        })
   }
   </div>
 )
   }
 }

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
.active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: Really helped me in un-selecting already clicked item in the list.! Thanks brother! 1+...

Comment: One question though, when we click on the already selected button, how react know which button is pressed for unsetting css class. Perhaps, because of using `key={index}` react know which index needs to unset the class? If I am wrong please explain a bit for concept only. thank you ;)

Comment: Hey mate any idea about my queries? Sorry to bother you!!

Comment: @LearningROR Hey! Yes you can relay on key={index} which is passed to handler function

Comment: Thanl you brother. :) Makes sense.